# having trouble creating an array of constants (java)

Tags: java, arrays

hey guys im having a little bit of a problem creating an array of constants in an interface. these constants will be used to store some menu choices in a frame

```
public interface Constants
{
    int X_POS       = 100,
    Y_POS       = 320,
    X_FACTOR    =   2,
    Y_FACTOR    =   3;

    String [] MENU_CHOICE  = ("File", "Edit", "Help");

    String TITLE    = "My First Java Graphical User Interface";

 }
```

the MENU_CHOICE array keeps giving me syntax error. it says that (  ")", "", "=") expected.

Comment: Replace `()` to `{}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should construct your array of strings using `{ }`

Like this

`String [] MENU_CHOICE  = {"File", "Edit", "Help"};`

Comment: it says i have to wait 10 minutes but will do

Answer (score 5):

You need *braces* instead of *parenthesis*:

```
String[] menuChoice  = {"File", "Edit", "Help"};
```

Please make your variables *camelCase*, instead of *ALL-CAPS*.

Comment: @Azad. Take it in whatever way you want. I just gave an answer that is quite an answer.

Comment: Yes, I see, it's exactly what the tag says, with respects off course.

Answer (score 0):

You need curly braces {} not brackets () on your array declaration.